# GIS: Alternative ways of patching gaps in a polygon

Tags: gis, arcgis, qgis

I'm working in QGIS but I can also use ArcGIS if there's a solution that works best on there.

I have a shapefile with certain plots of land highlighted and I plan to calculate the distance of features to the borders of these plots. But the plots have the roads and rivers going through them as gaps in the polygons. Like this:

[image]

Of course, this messes with the distance calculation I want. The goal is to create new polygons that just the outline only. I have tried the hole function in QGIS. I also tried buffering with dissolving then reversing the buffer. What other methods might work to fill in the gaps?

Comment: I think your question if off-topic in this site (about programming). We have a sister-site about gis (links on top right icon) which may be more relevant. OTOH I think you are looking the problem on the wrong side. Get the correct polygon (e.g. region, etc., which should not contain roads). You are using a derived shapefile which cut off features (in order to classify different categories. You can merge features, etc. but it will be too complex and too many case it will go wrong.

Comment: You're right, thanks! I'll ask there instead.